# File uploading is not working on live server

Tags: php, file-upload, cpanel, plesk

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/images/24_silver_2_1.jpg): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\leojungen.com\httpdocs\launch-complaint.php on line
>   72
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\Windows\Temp\php19A2.tmp' to '/images/24_silver_2_1.jpg' in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\leojungen.com\httpdocs\launch-complaint.php on line
>   72

```
function uploadMultipleFiles($complaintId){
    global $_pdo;$path = '';
    // Count # of uploaded files in array
    $total = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
    // Loop through each file
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
            //Setup our new file path
            $newFilePath = "/images/".$complaintId."_".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            //echo "path: "; print_r($_SERVER);exit;
            move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath,$newFilePath);
        }
        $path .= $complaintId."_".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]."^";
    }
}
```

In my local environment everything is working file, but when i deployed it on live, it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because either the directory `/images` is not present on the server or `write permission` on that directory is missing. Check and fix this and try again.

Comment: Yes It says,
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/26_grey_2.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\leojungen.com\httpdocs\launch-complaint.php on line 72

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php3891.tmp' to 'images/26_grey_2.jpg' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\leojungen.com\httpdocs\launch-complaint.php on line 72

Answer (score 1):

```
$newFilePath = "/images/".$complaintId."_".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
```

change this to

```
$newFilePath = "images/".$complaintId."_".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
```

Comment: Did it, it now giving permissions issue,
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/26_grey_2.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\leojungen.com\httpdocs\launch-complaint.php on line 72

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php3891.tmp' to 'images/26_grey_2.jpg' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\leojungen.com\httpdocs\launch-complaint.php on line 72

Comment: Make sure that you have write permission on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

instead of :
 $newFilePath = "/images/".$complaintId."_".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

please try the below :

$newFilePath = "./images".$complaintId."_".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

the Period in ./images means root/images....if there are other in between root and images..include it

I know its very old question but I am posting this answer so that if any newcoder like me comes...he get the solution that worked for me